# Avoid the non-null assertion operator when assign object members

Tags: angular, typescript

Searching for a pragmatic way to set or assign object members to an other object avoid the non-null assertion operator "!".
For the exmaple below assume `formData` can be an arbitrary JS object.

some.component.ts

```
export class SomeComponent {
  someModel: SomeModel; 
constructor( ) {  
  this.someModel.set(formData);
 }
}
```

some-model.model.ts

```
export class SomeModel {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;

  constructor({ field1 = "", field2 = "" } = {}) { 
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
  }
  setMembers({field1, field2}: {field1?: string | null, field2: string | null} = {}){
    this.field1 = field1 !== null && field1 !== undefined ? field1 : this.field1;
    this.field2 = field2 !== null && field2 !== undefined ? field2 : this.field2;
  }
}
```

Is there a shorter way to define `setMembers`, so that `setMembers` will only assign the parameters that are not null and not undefined?
I want something like the generic approach below, where setMembers is reusable for other models and independent of the amount of parameters:

```
  setMembers(data: Partial<Model>): void {
    ModelHelper.set(this, data);
  }
```

model/model-helper.ts

```
export class ModelHelper {
  static set<T>(model: T, data: Partial<T>): void {
    for (const key of Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof T>) {
      if (data[key] !== null && data[key] !== undefined) {
         model[key] = data[key] as T[keyof T];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But therefor I run into the "Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'" issue again.

So I have to redefine the signature as:

```
interface IModel {
  [key: string]: any;
}
setMembers(data: Partial<IModel>): void {
    ModelHelper.set(this, data);
  }
```

Comment: you're using reactive forms so typing the form will avoid lot of the work you're doing. And form.getRawValue() won't be partial if you're not using disabled aspect of forms. Your form is simple enough that I'd recommend template forms which bypasses the issue by having a model which serves as your type

Comment: I don't know much about angular so maybe this is off-base, but if you wanted a factory function to generate setters for you, you could maybe do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/N9QX1N).  Let me know if this is what you're looking for and I'll write it up as an answer if so. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz , yes this is what I tried to achieve with the generic Helper class that provides a setter for the model (or each type of model like your factory function) and avoid the long signatures and amount of similar checks in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a factory function that takes a set of key names, and produces an appropriate `setMembers()` method that behaves how you want.  It could look like this:

```
function makeSetter<K extends PropertyKey>(...keys: K[]) {
  return function <T extends Record<K, any>>(
    this: T, data: { [P in K]?: T[P] | null | undefined } = {}) {
    keys.forEach(k => this[k] = data[k] ?? this[k]);
  }
}
```

The returned method uses a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) to only allow it being called on objects with properties that match the keys in `keys`.  And it accepts an  [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) `data` argument.  The `data` argument's properties are also [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties), and their types should be the same as that of the corresponding properties on the object on which the method is being called, except that they can also be `null` or `undefined`.

The implementation uses [the nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) so that the property of the `data` argument is copied unless it is `null` or `undefined`.

---

The easiest way to use `makeSetter()` would be like this:

```
class SomeModel {
  field1: string = "";
  field2: string = "";
  constructor() { }
  setMembers = makeSetter("field1", "field2");
}

const m = new SomeModel();
m.setMembers({ field1: "abc" });
/* (property) SomeModel.setMembers: <SomeModel>(this: SomeModel, data?: {
  field1?: string | null | undefined;
  field2?: string | null | undefined;
}) => void */
```

So when a `SomeModel` instance is constructed, the `setMembers` property will be initialized with the result of `makeSetter("field1", "field2")`, the desired setter method for `SomeModel`.

Of course this ends up running `makeSetter` unnecessarily for each instance of `SomeModel`.  You can make exactly one of them instead:

```
const setModelMembers = makeSetter("field1", "field2");
class SomeModel {
  field1: string = "";
  field2: string = "";
  constructor() { }
  setMembers = setModelMembers;
}
```

And even this unnecessarily creates a `setMembers` instance property for each instance of `SomeModel`, when it would ideally be a method on the prototype. This is possible but you need to tell TypeScript to expect such a thing:

```
class SomeModel {
  field1: string = "";
  field2: string = "";
  constructor() { }
  declare setMembers: typeof setModelMembers;
}
SomeModel.prototype.setMembers = setModelMembers;
```

---

And now you hopefully have something you can use for different classes:

```
class Foo {
  a = 1; b = ""; c = true;
  setMembers = makeSetter("a", "b", "c");
}
const f = new Foo();
f.setMembers({ a: "", c: false }); // error!
// ----------> ~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
f.setMembers({ a: 3, b: "x" });
console.log(f) // {a: 3, b: "x", c: false}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgGYCuw8ALgJYD2wSYIA1hAMoSWUQBOAPAGkkEAB7dgAEyhIACj1oxelAJ4CIygHwAKAHR7WyqAC4kAgNoBdAJR5CRJD06keDMhRr0kfACrCxESWkAJQh4Wh4JQQAaJBBgTW07eyRKAAtqYyRvGIkQShATXCQzGSRqBgELAH4TbxKLJAAfJGBSDAwmpHIJCGJyiAkkAF8kAF48IZsCZKIDKB1icIBRBFStZjGNFPSoM2YG8dz8vYaqqu2Mk6sAbiThuyH8O1BIWARkAElgKHyKCDkFLY7mFvpQkFBOABZWg9DCQiBgABGvGk4yYrA4XF4WgARH0IBgJABGHExPHUAkSABMOJuwIwICg0jYtEg0NhthmJAphKJJh+PHKAHMxkgcTjblz8YSqfzKILgCLxuLJTMQQLSFRwlopvcuRDKPCkSjRQb2QSjcieFBVURHsD6D9GKLgBAAO5IFlsmEEnW2pDq2gYCA6DC0IVaMB05JgHRmhFWqBaIrS4kmHEgRHwHHDaP2AD0ACokFoYPJFDwVDYvRBzRg41CEyiTHwa3XtGkMiY2z6MDk8iAapyZqmiUOBcLOq12p1ur1+hJ-URU1Tx-LJ81px1mnO+q7F3dJpskAA3WjUQaF-MO75BkNhiNR-2x+PG63J7mU2VinrEHOTf1A2DUNw0jPMiBfRs3yTcCA0dO8QMfPN7SIF5oDgRAkHhNIYWHIh1TBM1e0tE00RYdhOG4HhcVHUkxRXWlbnpRlmVZWtezw+xRzlBUlTFCU7mXHlqR4ydlQErkCJ4TVKG1XVHi5Hp4AZRxwSgxMTBURRaGINTDWIptrX9BT7B7WEdDLWhZK0kNX0TU0oQM6CmOSAjnXGV0PTM31YKA+9QKjO5IMNQykxTYS+TFTNs1zQD4OAh8wKChsQugj8V3TX9-18+L-KQp47QKgMGSZJAADFaFoTiQFFIlriQRFRRVANRXlUgIH9OzSMYcjMSo3EQDonFESG7NkLsNzdI891ysqv07GIFKSPfIoCn4mJ4BMYhMAhWKkHzfNhB4eQeAAQjsA6kAAWhu267q2AA-C7Du8ZRFCQAByCdFQ+sppGAKzYiZaghVARFgxSKqbM+1o3w+nQFqW0KPzWgBmGJEXTERstVPzEK0YgbEu3A0YxrG6M2kgdogR57SeemGcZxmgA)